# Cosmos DB set Indexing Policy through Azure RM

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm

I am trying to set the indexing policy for Cosmos DB Account to none from Azure RM powershell scripts but no luck.

```
  $tableProperties = @{
    resource=@{ id=$table; indexingPolicy= @{indexingMode="none"; automatic = "false"; includedPaths = "[]"; excludedPaths = "[]" }  };
     options=@{ Throughput= 500 }
}

  Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceType $tableResourceType `
        -ApiVersion $apiVersion -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        -Name $tableResourceName -PropertyObject $tableProperties -Force
```

Indexing Policy node from Cosmos DB

```
{
"indexingMode": "consistent",
"automatic": true,
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*"
    }
],
"excludedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
    }
]
```

}

Update:
Tried:

```
$containerResourceType = "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/tables"
$containerName = $destinationStorageName+"/"+ $table

$containerGet = Get-AzResource -ResourceType $containerResourceType `
    -ApiVersion $apiVersion -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $containerName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties

$containerProperties = @{
    "resource"=@{
        "id"=$containerGet.resource.id; 
        "indexingPolicy"=@{"indexingMode"="none"}
    }
}

Set-AzResource -ResourceType $containerResourceType `
-ApiVersion $apiVersion -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-Name $containerName -PropertyObject $containerProperties -Force
```

No luck

Answer (score 1):

For the indexing policy you only need to set indexingMode to none. Also child resources in Cosmos do not support PATCH so for any PUT on a resource you need to include any other properties which have been set, including partitionKey which is required. See example below.

Update: this sample uses AzResource as AzureRM has been deprecated.

```
$apiVersion="2019-08-01"
$containerResourceType = "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers"
$resourceGroupName="myResourceGroup"
$containerName = "mycosmosaccount/myDatabase/myContainer"

$containerGet = Get-AzResource -ResourceType $containerResourceType `
    -ApiVersion $apiVersion -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $containerName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties

$containerProperties = @{
    "resource"=@{
        "id"=$containerGet.resource.id; 
        "partitionKey"=$containerGet.resource.partitionKey;
        "indexingPolicy"=@{"indexingMode"="none"}
    }
}

Set-AzResource -ResourceType $containerResourceType `
    -ApiVersion $apiVersion -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $containerName -PropertyObject $containerProperties -Force
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the response. I am using tableAPI and not SQL. I tried the script that I later updated in the answer, but no luck :(

Comment: Well that explains it because there is no index policy for Table API. Indexing policy only applies to SQL API.